# Display all images from a folder in a WordPress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom WordPress page template and I want to show all the pictures I created in a folder inside my template:  mypics.  I created this php script but is not working (it shows a broken link):

```
    $base_dir = bloginfo('template_url');
    $media_dir = $base_dir.'/mypics/';

    $files = glob($media_dir.'{*.jpg,*.png}', GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach ($files as $image){
       echo '<img src="'.$media_dir.$image.'" />';
    };
```

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: The `$files` array should return the full path of the image, there is no need to prepend the `$media_dir` to the `$image` path I think.

Comment: I tried echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="'.$image.'" />'; but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As Terry pointed out in the comments, the `$files` array should contain the full server path to the files. However, since you need the domain-relative path, you should strip out the server path. Try changing your code to the following:

```
$base_dir = bloginfo('template_url');
$media_dir = $base_dir.'/mypics/';

$files = glob($media_dir.'{*.jpg,*.png}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($files as $image){
   echo '<img src="'.$media_dir.basename($image).'" />';
};
```

I'm using `basename` to get just the name of the file and concatenating it to your directory.

If the above doesn't work, make sure to print out the value of `$media_dir` to make sure it is correct.

Comment: It doesn't work, I printed $media_dir and it shows the right path.